# PCF Dev Spring Cloud Config Server Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, spring-cloud-config, pcf, pcfdev

I'm trying to configure a p-config-server instance to use GitLab.The account has a password. I have tried both the http and ssh urls with username and password for the http url and a private key for the ssh url.

The service reports that it failed to start. But I can't get any more information as to why it failed.

1. How do I configure this correctly to connect to a GitLab instance?
2. Where are the logfiles for the service failure so that I can find the issues?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The username and password eventually worked.

I used -c with a file containing :-

```
{
  "git": {
    "uri": "http://host:port/xyz.git",
    "label": "master",
    "username": "demo",
    "password": "demouser"
  }
}
```